# How perform natural full outer join in table having multiple attributes common?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, full-outer-join, natural-join

mysql> select * from r;

```
+------+------+------+
| A    | B    | C    |
| 1    | 2    | 3    |
| 1    | 2    | 4    |
| 2    | 1    | 3    |
| 3    | 1    | 3    |
+------+------+------+
```

mysql> select * from s;

```
+------+------+------+
| A    | B    | D    |
| 1    | 2    | 1    |
| 2    | 1    | 5    |
| 4    | 2    | 1    |
| 3    | 2    | 1    |
+------+------+------+
```

Now I want to perform natural full outer join. I have tried left outer join and right outer join and full outer join but they are performing while have taken only 1 element in common.

But how will it be done here.

The question is asking for number of rows contain null entries in table r natural full outer join s.

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired output/

Comment: I think "natural full outer join" is not a thing: A 'natural join' can't be 'outer'/an 'outer' join can't be 'natural'. Please give the result you expect for your sample `r natural_full_outer_join s`. Also give the query and result from the full outer join you tried, and explain what you thought was wrong about it. (I see @Gordon's answer; I've no idea whether it's giving what you expect. As he says, nullable columns in `r, s` makes it a lot more tricky.)

Answer (score 0):

You can "chain" left joins to implement a very good approximation to a `full join`:

```
select *
from (select a, b from r
      union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select a, b from s
     ) rs left join
     r
     using (a, b) left join
     s
     using (a, b);
```

This becomes trickier if `a`/`b` could have `NULL` values in the `r` or `s`.  If that is the case, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Re the "remove duplicates", why not just `select distinct * ...` at the outer level?

Comment: @AntC . . . The logic is different.  The `full join` might actually produce duplicates, and this logic would also create duplicates.  `select distinct` in the outer query would remove duplicates so it is not equivalent to a `full join`.

Comment: Emm you're the guy who thinks 'Natural Join is a disaster waiting to happen.' IIRC. And now you actually _want_ to introduce duplicates. Aren't duplicates a much worse disaster waiting to happen?

Comment: @AntC . . . That doesn't answer the question correctly.  The question is about implementing the equivalent of a natural join.  The OP is free to ask a *new* question that has other logic.